# External links won't open

Tags: javascript, html

I am a noob with anything JS, I have a menubar for a onepage website that works to scroll the page but will not open external links, could one of you guys please help? Code Below, site can be viewed at http://protocol-labs.com/new

html

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#banner">Home</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#service">Services</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#testimonial">Testimonial</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>        
    </ul>
</div>
```

js that is causing the issue

```
(function ($) {

// Add smooth scrolling to all links in navbar
$(".navbar a,a.btn-appoint, .quick-info li a, .overlay-detail a").on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var hash = this.hash;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
    }, 900, function(){
        window.location.hash = hash;
    });
});

//jQuery to collapse the navbar on scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(".navbar-default").offset().top > 50) {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
    } else {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
    }
});   
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` disables the default functionality of anchors, so they do not lead to their `href` destination.

Comment: How are your `<div>`'s defined on the page? `<div id="banner>`, `<div id="about">` etc?

Comment: Whats the exact question ? Do you want them to open an external link or what ?

Comment: Hmmm...I tested your code and I don't see any problem. Unless you've literally just forgot to put an ID to each divs.

Answer (score 1):

You have prevent default attached to your anchor event. This prevents the link from working.

```
$(".navbar a,a.btn-appoint, .quick-info li a, .overlay-detail a").on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevents link from working. Remove it and you should be good.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add  a special class to all links with anchors (the first 4 ones) and call the function just by clicking these links, keeping the standard behavoir by clicking at `<a href="contact.html">Contact</a>`

Answer (score 0):

I modified both js as well as html codes: (I guess this code is part of Medilab+ Template)
JS / JQuery

```
(function ($) {

// Add smooth scrolling to all links in navbar
$(".navbar2").on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var hash = this.hash;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
    }, 900, function(){
        window.location.hash = hash;
    });
});

//jQuery to collapse the navbar on scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(".navbar-default").offset().top > 50) {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
    } else {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
    }
});})(jQuery);
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="myNavbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home" class="navbar2" style="padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;">Home</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="service.html#service" style="padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;">Services</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#about" class="navbar2" style="padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;">About</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="contact.html#contact" style="padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```